# What does call digest in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I use

`<span> {{myFunc()}} </span>`

when I open my app, I see that `myFunc` gets called around 85 times when the app boots up.

Why, or better, what, does make `$digest` typically get called that many times?

the function myFunc is called setName like this

```
                scope.setName = function(scp) {
                    if (typeof $rootScope.newValue === 'undefined' || !$rootScope.newValue)
                        return $filter('translate')('myapp.initial.name');
                    else if (typeof scp.baby !== 'undefined' && scp.baby.name !== null && scp.baby.name !== ""){
                        return scp.baby.name;
                    }
                    else{
                        return $rootScope.newValue;
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code. i suspect that you have this inside a repeating structure. Also, digests will always run at least twice, and more if scope changes occur during a digest cycle

Comment: well no it is actually not in a repeating structure. It is in a directive though, but is only used once

Comment: @charlietfl the template part of the directive looks like this `..., template: '<span data-translate>{{setName($root)}}</span>',`

Comment: that function itself could be causing extra digests if it isn't returning the same  value during a digest cycle .... where's the code?

Comment: i added the function that was called, is it the code you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a digest is triggered by an event. It could be a timer, an XHR call or a user interaction.
But a running digest could trigger other digests, until the model is stabilized, or until a maximum number of *looping digests* is reached. By default this maximum number, known as *TTL (Time To Live)* in angular code, is defined to 10.

Comment: so I change to the model / scope would result typically in a digest? sure, you call call `apply()` but that is the obvious case. What else leads to digest getting called?

Comment: You call explicitely `apply` only when you're outside angular context. Most of the time, angular calls it implicitely for you. Could you reproduce the problem of the question in a fiddle / plunkr? Might be interesting to analyze what's going on.

Comment: I think for me it would be enough, to know what typically calls implicitly the digest. Reproducing the error is close to impossible because the app is big... i just stumbled upon it and wondered why this functions gets called so many times. I understand that the watchers are a handy thing, but it seems nonperformance if all watchers get called close to a hundred times each time the app starts?

Comment: i mean, since this function gets called that many times, all other watchers are getting called as well I reckon?